# Examples for a Golomb's result, and rationals as $\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{|G_n|}{P(n)}$, where $G_n$ are Gregory coefficients and $P(x)$ a polynomial

Tags: analytic-number-theory, sequences-and-series, examples, counterexamples, irrational-numbers

After I was stuying the first pages of a chapter of the book [1], in particular the statement of **Corollary 10.3** and its proof,  I wondered what can be interesting examples of irrational numbers that are represented by this type of series.

I am asking about examples with a good mathematical content. My examples were or well obvious examples or well examples arising when I invoke symbolically major results for the asymptotics of certain arithmetic functions. These are summarized in next paragraph.

**Fact.** A) *Golomb result implies that* $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2^k}+C_k}$$
*is an irrational number, where* $C_k$ *denotes the so-called Cullen numbers.*
B) *We denote the primorial of order* $k$ *as* $N_k=\prod_{t=1}^k p_t$, *the product of the first* $k$ *primes, then Golomb result implies that* $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{2^{2^k}+N_k}$$
*is an irrational number.* C) *We denote the Stirling numbers of the second kind as* ${n\brace m}$, *then* (notice that my example was the more cheap that I can to get from the asymptotic of Stirling numbers of the second kind) $\forall a>1$ *integer, one has that the series* $$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{a^{2^k}+{k\brace a}}$$
*represents to an irrational number as a consequence of Golomb's result.*

> **Question 1 (Relevant examples of Golomb's result)** Can you create a similar but more relevant example to illustrate, if possible, the Golomb's result that I've evoked? My examples or well are obvious examples or well are examples arising when I invoke symbolically major results for the asymptotics of certain arithmetic functions. Can you improve my strategy to provide nice computations and reasonings for an example of irrational number as consequence of Golomb's result? **Many thanks.**

I am triying to read some sections of a Tijdeman's article. I am inspired to speculate if one can to find a rational number of the form $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|G_n|}{Q(n)},$$
where $G_n$ denote the so-called Gregory coefficients, please see the Wikipedia [*Gregory coefficients*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_coefficients), and $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$, a polynomial with integer coefficients, such that $Q(n)>0$ for all integers $n\geq 1$ and satisfies that its degree $\deg(Q)>1$. Due that Gregory coefficients have an integral representation, that it is Schröder's integral formula I think that my question is answerable, see also the series related to the sequence of Gregory coefficients.

> **Question 2 (Counterexamples for a speculation).** My belief is that *for each* $Q(x)\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ *satisfying* $Q(n)>0$ *for all* $n\geq 1$ *and*  $\deg(Q)>1$ *the series* $$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{|G_n|}{Q(n)}$$ *will be an irrational number*. Can you find a counterexample? **Many thanks.**

I add below the references. I wanted to ask two questions, because I think that maybe each question alone does not justify an MO post since I am asking just for examples and counterexamples. In addition it is as a small repository of examples and counterexamples of irrationals from sequences related to analytic number theory.

### References:

[1] Michael Křižek, Florian Luca and Lawrence Somer, *17 Lectures on Fermat Numbers*, CMS Books in Mathematics, Canadian Mathematical Society, Springer-Verlag (2001).

[2] S. W. Golomb, *On the sum of the reciprocals of the Fermat numbers and related irrationalities*, Canad. J. Math **15** (1963) MR 27 # 105.

[3] R. Tijdeman, *On Irrationality and Transcendency of Infinite Sums of Rational Numbers*, from *Diophantine Equations*, Editor: N. Saradha, Tata Institute of Fundamental Research, Narosa Publishing House (2008).

Comment: For all users interested in this question, sure that it is interesting also to think for future explorations in variants of the series of section **B14** showed in Richard K. Guy, *Unsolved Problems in Number Theory*, Unsolved problems in Intuitive Mathematics Volume I, Second Edition, Springer-Verlag (1994).

Comment: I am fed up with your constant failure to include definitions or even links for important concepts in your posts here. What in blazes are the "so-called Gregory coefficients"?

Comment: I'm sorry @GerryMyerson , I've added/linked the definition. Many thanks.